# Why less when you can have more? (Pagers on *Nix)

Tags: linux

Why do Linux people and most programs -- Ruby commands, for instance -- use `less` instead of `more`. Isn't more bigger, nicer, and better? **What is the advantage to `less`?**

Comment: your next assignment is to determine the differences between cat and dog, and why the latter never took off... :D

Comment: dog is nice, also most is a decent pager.

Comment: dog support was discontinued after Debian Lenny and Ubuntu Jaunty :'(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally `more` only allowed forward motion in the file while `less` allowed you to move freely in the viewed file.

Modern version of `more` is more versatile.

I think the two wiki pages for [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_%28command%29) and [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) shows the current difference quite well.

Comment: so maybe more is more now?

Comment: @Yar - Naw, less is still more :-)

Comment: First thing I do on any *nix machine is make sure my pager is less.

Answer (score 9):

Because [less is more than more](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/less-is-more-than-more-on-linux/)...

> less does not have to read the entire
>   input file before starting, so with
>   large input files it starts up faster
>   than text editors like vi (1). Less
>   uses termcap (or terminfo on some
>   systems), so it can run on a variety
>   of terminals. There is even limited
>   support for hardcopy terminals. (On a
>   hardcopy terminal, lines which should
>   be printed at the top of the screen
>   are prefixed with a caret.)

Comment: Nice! glad I asked

Comment: more doesn't read the entire input file either…

Comment: @Tobu, you mean more?

Comment: @Yar I do. None of the pagers read the entire input until necessary. The main advantage of less is the one Nifle describes.

Comment: @Tobu, what is the main advantage? That `less` USED TO be the only one to allow you to go backwards? Also, why is my `more` command running `less` on OSX? This is beginning to sound like a conspiracy.

Comment: @Yar: Backwards compatibility. Many people and programs pipe to `more`, and changing that to `less` without anything in /bin/more's place would break lots of stuff, including people's minds. "$OperatingSystem is broken! It doesn't have more!"

Comment: The OP wanted help comparing `less` to `more`. There are a few issues with this answer.

Comment: 1. Both `less` and `more` don't read the entire input file on start-up.
  2. From `man less`, "Less  is  a program similar to more (1), but which allows backward movement in the file as well as forward movement." This paragraph, which precedes the quoted text in the answer, describes the fundamental difference between `less` and `more`. (The quoted text is itself copied from the Description section of `man less`.)
  3. The link's author described what to him was the main deficiency of "more" in the paragraph that preceded the quoted text in the answer.

Comment: "For starters I use dual-monitors and I expect to be able to view the log (maillog) conveniently in a single line. more works as long as the terminal width isn’t too long. Apparently it has a limit on maximum number of characters beyond which it will automatically wrap around even if my terminal is wider. That is irritating to say the least. less does a fine job with wide terminals."

Comment: Hence, the main advantage of `less` over `more` is due to `less` supporting both backward and forward movement. It's not because `less` doesn't read the entire input file on start-up while `more` does (since this is not correct).

Answer (score 3):

"Most programs-- Ruby commands, for instance", should be using whatever pager is the default instead of explicitly using a particular one. You can set your preferred pager via the $PAGER environment variable, and any properly behaving program will use that pager. I recommend checking out most as well. view can be nice if you are a fan of vi.

Does anyone know of a pager that has emacs keybindings out of the box (or, even better, a way to use emacsclient as a pager that accepts data from stdin)?

Comment: @Justin Smith, thanks for that. Make your question a proper question and it shall be answered (not by me, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware to the `most` [pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_%28Unix%29), adding the capability of viewing multiple files simultaneously.