# Is 'more' dead on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell

[Just when I was getting curious about less vs. more](https://superuser.com/questions/103481/why-less-when-you-can-have-more-pagers-on-nix/103482#103482)

I am running Snow Leopard. When I type `more` it says

`Missing filename ("less --help" for help)`

So I type `whereis more` and it says `/usr/bin/more`. Okay, so I run that and it says the same thing. Even `man more` says

```
NAME
       less - opposite of more
```

**Was `more` killed as part of my Snow Leopard install, or was it something else that I installed that did this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether Leopard had it when I was running it. I just don't use `more`; `less` is just so much more powerful. Both `man more` and `man less` open the same manpage, which is that of `less`. If you look at the sizes of the files `/usr/bin/more` and `/usr/bin/less`, they are identical. The two binaries are identical as well.

Comment: cool, at least it's not me

Comment: yes, they are identical (there's a hardlink from less to more)  stat output that shows this: 

stat more -> inode   11892499
stat less -> inode   11892499

Much like vi and view.

Comment: Thanks @skarface, I had no idea that two filenames could point to the same resource. That's different than a symbolic link, I suppose.

Comment: @Yar: Also try `ls -li {/usr,}/bin/{less,more}`. The `-i` will show the inodes and the brace expansion will show the various locations (including errors if they don't exist in those locations). `type -a less more` will show locations, aliases and function definitions (but not inodes or whether symlinks exist).

Answer (score 3):

For quite some time a lot of linux distributions have aliased or symlinked `more` to `less`, I assume OSX has done the same thing.

Chances are that you never had the *original* `more` installed.

Comment: @Yar: By contrast, `more` on my system is its own binary. While it's much more capable than the original `more`, it still falls far short of `less`. The version of `more` I have doesn't report a version number, but it's part of the `util-linux-ng` on Ubuntu 9.10. Another pager that you might like to take a look at is [`most`](http://www.jedsoft.org/most/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Williamson, I will check out `most` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, my level is too low to comment on one of the other answers... so here's an out-of-line comment:  On Leopard, both more and less can be found in /usr/bin, with the same file size, date, and length.  Interestingly neither is a link to the other:

-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  254288 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/less

-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  254288 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/more

So I guess Snow Leopard is indeed different, I didn't add these.

Comment: They are linked, just with a hardlink, not a symbolic link, which is why you don't see the -> in ls.  Take a look at my comment above, stat shows that they are both on the same inode.

Comment: Is it possible to make our own hardlinks?

Comment: @macek: Yes, just use `ln`. Nicely explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

Answer (score 1):

As noted *more* & *less* are actually the same binary, but it behaves differently depending on which name was used to run it, so you get the benefits of both.

Comment: example? I thought that it performs the same